# Plural for "photo"?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, british-english, orthography, greek

What's the proper plural for "photo" - "photos", "photoes", or it is generally desired to rephrase the whole thing and stick with "photographs", "images", "shots", "pictures", etc?

As for usage frequency, quick Google search reveals that:

- "photos" => ~5,380,000,000 ghits
- "photoes" => ~3,340,000 ghits, which is ~1000 times less often used, although some of the results point to English grammar forums where some people suggest that "photoes" might be indeed *correct* form given Greek origin of the word

Dictionary check reveals:

- [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/photo?q=photo) clearly gives plural as "photos", but suggests that "photoes" is a verb
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photo) gives plural as "photos", but does not recognize "photoes" as a valid word at all, albeit it does recognize "photoed" as a verb
- [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/photo?q=photo) gives "photos", clearly makes it as AmE-only and also insists that there's no verb - i.e. no "photoes", no "photoed", no "photoing"
- [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/photo) agreed on "photos" and agreed on that verb does not exist
- [Douglas-Harper Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=photo&allowed_in_frame=0) tells us that both noun and verb exist - the noun is since 1860, the verb is first recorded 1868, from the noun.

I'm kind of hesitating here. If you'd ask me, I'd rather opt for not using plural forms of "photo" at all - both "photos" and "photoes" feel somewhat awkward for me (as do "audios", "videos" or "alphas" / "betas" / "gammas" / "deltas").

So, generally, what's the most neutral way to refer to a group of photographs? Bonus points for revealing BrE/AmE differences.

Comment: Of course 'Bonus points'

Comment: It's always *photos* or if you prefer something even shorter, *pics*.

Comment: In the [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/photo?q=photo) *photos* is the plural of the noun, whereas *photoes* is the third person singular conjugate of the verb *photo*.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Thanks, I've added some dictionary reference!

Comment: I would suggest that using *photo/photoes* as a present-tense verb is unusual to the point of non-existence. Even ODO has *photoed* (past tense) in their example. But there's nothing wrong with *photos* as a plural.

Comment: The verbs *go* and *do* in the 3rd person singular are *goes* and *does*; the nouns *potato* (s)  *potatoes* and *hero* (s) *heroes* (pl) follow the same pattern, hence  some people apply the same spelling convention for *photo*. Just write *photos* always, and without the apostrophe. I often see native speakers write *photo's* when they mean the plural form.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен - No, "photoes" are when you have the camera pointing at your feet and accidentally take a picture.

Comment: What is the question? I mean, why do you not accept the results of your own research?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Photoes* seems to have peaked in the 1950s and the usage of *photo* vs *photoes* nowadays is about ten to one according to Google's Ngram.  I am a native speaker of American English and I suspect *photoes* is significantly more common in non-US usage.  It just looks like a spelling error to my American eyes.