# Why is the plural form of piano "pianos" and not "pianoes"?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, suffixes, vowels, silent-letters

The rule says that if a singular noun ends in consonant + "o" then the plural form will be consonant + "oes".

e.g. *tomato* => *tomatoes.*

Then, why this rule does not apply to *piano*?

Comment: The exception proves the rule.  "Piano" is a word of Italian origin and Italian words ending in "o" form the plural by adding only "s".   The same for "casino"    casino - casinos

Comment: Because the First Rule in the English language is that no rule works 100% of the time. And when I say "no rule" I include the First Rule...

Comment: The rule is wrong. English spelling is chaotic and has to be learned individually. Don't trust any English spelling rules; there will always be many exceptions (and anyone who states the rule will never tell you all of them, because they don't know, either).

Comment: Geese, moose, sheep to name a few other random pluralisations

Comment: related: [Plural for “photo”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134628/plural-for-photo) and [What is the correct plural of “octopus”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-correct-plural-of-octopus)

Comment: Maybe Dan Quail could help you on this one....

Comment: @Centaurus - I came across this on some websites, that for musical instruments banzo, piano etc it is banzos or pianos. And it also said that these words came from Italian words. This is perhaps another way to get it right at times.

Comment: @TheRoy Do you mean "banjo"? I've never heard of a "banzo" and can't find an instrument called a "banzo" through Google. If you do mean banjo then it's etymology isn't Italian, it seems to be English derived from various African languages. Not only that but "banjoes" is an acceptable alternative plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plural of nouns ending in [-o](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/plurals-of-nouns):

> Nouns ending in -o can add either -s or -es in the plural, and some can be spelled either way.
>
> As a general rule, most nouns ending in -o add -s to make the plural:

So you have:

> solo  solos,
> zero    zeros,
> avocado avocados

Note that:

> Those which have a vowel before the final -o always just add -s:

like:

> studio    studios,
> zoo zoos,
> embryo  embryos.

So:

> piano, pianos

Oxford Dictionary

Comment: You just missed answering the question and still it is accepted - that's bizarre. _**"Those which have a vowel before the final -o always just add -s like studio studios etc." So piano pianos?**_ How is `n` a **vovel**? The link thankfully is correct and it has specific examples of words ending with a consonants followed by a vowel using `es` as suffix for plural, like domino dominoes.

Comment: Some singular nouns ending with an *o* become plural without adding an *s*, e.g., *graffito* -> *graffiti*.

Answer (score 0):

By adding ‘s’ even to those ending in ‘o’ when the final ‘o’ is immediately preceded by a vowel:
studio          studios
radio           radios
curio           curios

By adding ‘es’ to those ending in ‘o’

hero            heroes
mango           mangoes
echo            echoes

But we also have examples of zero - zeros, piano - pianos etc., which do not follow the above rules.